# Python dictionary operations

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I remove the `data` key from this dictionary and convert it to this
using a python function recursively?

```
request = {"data":{"a":[{"data": {"b": {"data": {"c": "d"}}}}]}}

response = {"a": [{"b":{"c": "d"}}]}
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far and why is not working so we can help you?

Comment: Your description has problem, what if there is a "data" key but also another key, how to do for this level ?

Comment: I would need to ignore other keys, I am only concerned with "data" key and its value types are either list or dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this recursively, if all you have is lists and dictionaries, then that is pretty trivial. Test for the object type, and for containers, recurse:

```
def unwrap_data(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if 'data' in obj:
            obj = obj['data']
        return {key: unwrap_data(value) for key, value in obj.items()}

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [unwrap_data(value) for value in obj]

    return obj
```

Personally, I like using [the `@functools.singledispatch()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to create per-type functions to do the same work:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def unwrap_data(obj):
    return obj

@unwrap_data.register(dict)
def _handle_dict(obj):
    if 'data' in obj:
        obj = obj['data']
    return {key: unwrap_data(value) for key, value in obj.items()}

@unwrap_data.register(list)
def _handle_list(obj):
    return [unwrap_data(value) for value in obj]
```

This makes it a little easier to add additional types to handle later on.

Demo:

```
>>> request = {"data":{"a":[{"data": {"b": {"data": {"c": "d"}}}}]}}
>>> unwrap_data(request)
{'a': [{'b': {'c': 'd'}}]}
```